# Static DNS with DHCP on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, dhcp

Is it possible to get an [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) over [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) but force a [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) server instead of using the ones from the DHCP?

I should be able to do so with a static IP addresses, but I would like to know how to do it getting an IP address over DHCP. I thought that changing `/etc/resolv.conf` would be permanent, but it dismisses the changes after a reboot.

Comment: Shouldn't that file contain a line »DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN« ?

Comment: not in raspbian...

Comment: Not in stock debian either -- learned my lesson lol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only thing that worked for me was:

Edit /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf and un-comment the line:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222;
```

Anyway thanks for your for your help!

Answer (score 5):

dns-nameservers (and all others dns-xxx directives in /etc/network/interfaces) does not work in raspbian out of the box, since resolvconf is not installed by default.

sudo apt-get install resolvconf
solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this following the steps from [cuonglm's answer on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136117/ignore-dns-from-dhcp-server-in-ubuntu).

Edit the file **/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf** and add

```
supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
```

Then restart network or run dhclient to make changes.

From `man dhclient.conf`:

> The supersede statement
>
> ```
>    supersede [ option declaration ];
>
>    If for some option the client should always  use  a  locally-configured
>    value  or  values rather than whatever is supplied by the server, these
>    values can be defined in the supersede statement.
> ```

Comment: Raspbian version?

Answer (score 1):

You can define them with a line in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Underneath your interface, add the following line, replacing the x's with the actual IP of the DNS server:

`dns-nameservers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It didn't work for me, it keeps getting the DNS server from the DHCP. The one I used on the /etc/network/interfaces file was in second place.

Comment: This is a wheezy only answer. Does not apply to Jessie

Answer (score -1):

It's an old threat, but for current Raspbian/Debian you have to add at the end of /etc/dhcpcd.conf:

```
static domain_name_servers=1.1.1.1 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Why are you still using Jessie in 2020?

Comment: Sorry, my answer actually is for current Rapsbian (Buster) ! Please remove your downvote...

Comment: Sorry but I didn't downvote, and there is no way to tell who did.